# Asp.net mvc beta installation on VS2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, installation

I used to work with VWD and now I try to install the new MVC-Beta on VS2008.

Installation completes successfully but when I try to create an MVC web site I don't have it on the projects list. How can I fix it?

I've uninstalled VWD and MVC preview 5, tried to install several times the beta framework.

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio 2008 you have installed?

Comment: Do you have sp1 installed for both vs.net and .net 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did ensure that you did choose "New Project" instead of "New Website" from the File menu? You have to choose New Project or else the template won't appear.

Comment: Yes I have. Can't see the MVC project template